# Dominating families in bigger cardinals

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, cardinal-arithmetic

A dominating family on $\omega^\omega$ is a set $\mathcal D \subset \omega^\omega$ such that for every $f \in \omega^\omega$ there exists $g \in \mathcal D$ such that $f<^* g$ (that is, $f(n)<g(n)$ for all but a finite number of $n$'s). The smallest cardinality of a dominating family is $\mathfrak d$, and it is well known that $\omega_1\leq \mathfrak d\leq \mathfrak c$ and that it is consistent that $\mathfrak d$ may be almost everything between $\omega_1$ and $\mathfrak c$. I know that this is an important combinatorical concept and that it is widely used/studied.

I am interested in reading about some related questions. One may also define dominating families on $\omega^{\omega_1}$ and on $\omega_1^{\omega_1}$, and then define $\mathfrak d_{\omega_1, \omega}$ and $\mathfrak d_{\omega_1, \omega_1}$ in an analogous manner (so $\mathfrak d_{\omega, \omega}=\mathfrak d$).

I would like to know more about dominating families of higher cardinalities, so my main question is "where may I learn more about them?" Can someone please tell me some references?

Some questions (out of my mind) I would like to explore are:

1. It is easy to see that $\mathfrak d\leq \mathfrak d_{\omega_1, \omega}$. However, are they the same? What are the possible relations between them?
2. Since $\omega_1$ is regular, it is easy to see that $\omega_2\leq \mathfrak d_{\omega_1, \omega_1}\leq 2^{\omega_1}$. Is it consistent that $\mathfrak d_{\omega_1, \omega_1}<2^{\omega_1}$?
3. Is it consistent that $\mathfrak d_{\omega_1, \omega}=\omega_1$?

Answer (score 10):

Here is some general background information. The relevant search phrases for this topic are [generalized cardinal invariants](https://www.google.com/search?q=generalized+cardinal+invariants) or [generalized cardinal characteristics](https://www.google.com/search?q=generalized+cardinal+invariants), and the topic has a growing literature, emerging over many years. The topic has been studied as folklore for some time.

Here are a few specific resources:

- Dilip Raghavan, Saharon Shelah, Two results on cardinal invariants at uncountable cardinals, [arxiv.org:1801.09369](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09369).
- *Brendle, Jörg*, [**Cardinal invariants of the continuum and combinatorics on uncountable cardinals**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2006.05.003), Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 144, No. 1-3, 43-72 (2006). [ZBL1112.03046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1112.03046).
- Cichon's Diagram for uncountable cardinals, 
  Joerg Brendle, Andrew Brooke-Taylor, Sy-David Friedman, Diana Montoya
  [arxiv:1611.08140](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08140).
- *Brooke-Taylor, A.D.; Fischer, V.; Friedman, S.D.; Montoya, D.C.*, [**Cardinal characteristics at $\kappa$ in a small $\mathfrak{u}(\kappa)$ model**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2016.08.004),  [ZBL06643764](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06643764).
- Slides for a nice talk by Luke Serafin, [Cardinal invariants of the generalized continua](https://settheory.mathtalks.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/luke.pdf).

What you call $\mathfrak{d}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$ is known as $\mathfrak{d}_{\omega_1}$. Your concept of $\mathfrak{d}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ is less studied.

Comment: I think that there are many additional references, and perhaps others can mention them.

Answer (score 9):

Professor Hamkins already gave many interesting references. Let me add a few more.

Possibly, the work of Cummings-shelah [Cardinal invariants above the continuum](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016800729500003Y?via%3Dihub) is the starting point for the study of generalizations of  cardinal invariants to the context of uncountable cardinals. In this paper, they prove the following:  If $λ↦(β(λ),δ(λ),μ(λ))$ is a class function from regular cardinals into the cube of cardinals satisfying $λ^+≤β(λ)=cf(β(λ))≤cf(δ(λ))≤δ(λ)≤μ(λ)$ and $cf(μ(λ))>λ$ for all $λ$, then there exists a model where $b(λ)=β(λ), \mathfrak{d}(λ)=δ(λ)$, and $2^λ=μ(λ)$ for all $λ$.

for some other references see

- [Cardinal Invariants $\mathbf{b}_κ$ and $\mathbf{t}_κ$](http://shelah.logic.at/files/643.pdf).
- [Generalized Domination](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/113539/danhath_1.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).
- [Two inequalities between cardinal invariants](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.06296.pdf)
- [Adding dominating functions mod finite](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1004392507990)

Answer (score 3):

Two more references:
Monk,J.D. Notre Dame J. Formal Logic 45 (2004),129-146
Szymanski, A. Proc. AMS 104 (1988), 596-602.